# How to apply the laplace transform to this second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, nonlinear-system

Can I apply the Laplace transform on a the following second order nonlinear PDE?
$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 y^n}{\partial x^2}$$
where $n$ is a natural number?

I mean apply the transform to both $t$ and $x$ independently. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance.